# Porting Qt stylesheets app to a QStyle based one

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qstyle

According to [Say No to Qt Style Sheets](https://www.kdab.com/say-no-to-qt-style-sheets/), *"QStyle subclass is overall a much better solution for styling widgets than is Qt Style Sheets"*.

I've encountered some difficulties during porting my stylesheet app to a QStyle-ed one. The main question is: what is the way to define a class of a style for multiple widgets? For example, I have a stylesheet:

```
QLabel.Number { 
    border: 2px solid red; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: lightyellow; 
    color: red;
}
```

and each QLabels widget can get this style through

```
widget.setProperty("class", "Number");
```

How to realize this technique with QStyle approach?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to move away from stylesheets?  A random opinion from someone else, with no supporting evidence, seems a poor motivation.

Comment: I've found (and linked for you) the referenced article, and it does seem quite one-sided.  It is nowhere near popular consensus, and you may just be making unnecessary work for yourself.

Comment: @Toby Speight Why do you think it was a random opinion. By the way that article was full of weighty arguments. See https://www.kdab.com/say-no-to-qt-style-sheets/

Comment: Stylesheets also have big drawback: sometimes I want to change one trait in a widget, and it breaks all the style of widget (including paddings and fonts,  and backgrounnd gradients  and others) and makes it quite ugly. It is much slower in big projects, it works bad with dynamic properties. In a style-way you can easy value the widget extra states and take them in account. And so on.